# Defer DOM rendering in browser when there is any javascript in source

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I want to intervene with google chrome rendering mechanism with a browser extension 
e.g. the user wants to visit a webpage, I catch the webRequest (chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest) with background.script  and I want to block all DOM rendering if there is javascript code in the source of this tab.
There is an information I am looking for in the headers. I catch each time a batch of headers received by the browser (chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived) and look for the tag I want. During this time the javascript execution must be blocked. Since, I cannot make sure what the javascript is doing with the DOM, I have to defer rendering and browser stop rendering until I allow the browser to do.
If I find what I want in the headers I will do some measurements on it and then I can choose to allow or block DOM rendering from there on.

For some websites the rendering process is so quick, it doesn't wait for my comfort. For example, when I visit google.com, the webRequest is completed while I am still looking into the headers. So there is a race condition here.

My question : is there any way to defer browser rendering mechanism until I finish my work and allow it working?

I tried to block only javascript with chrome.contentSettings (even if it doesn't do what I want) but still some websites are quickly rendered and it doesn't wait until I allow javascript execution again.

Comment: Assuming you've already specified `'blocking'` in parameters of onHeadersReceived there's no such mechanism.